# Download button does not display

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, dotnetzip

I have a weird problem..

I am working on creating a thumbnail of a webpage! I have never worked with threading and I have a issue

I am using  the following code

```
protected void GetScreenshot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  path = Server.MapPath(FolderID);
  Thread webBrowseThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PerformWebBrowseOp));
  webBrowseThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
  webBrowseThread.Start();
}          

protected void PerformWebBrowseOp()
{
  if(searchedword!='')
  {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
  }

  string path1 = Mypath + "/image.png";
  GeneateScreenshot gn = new GeneateScreenshot();
  Bitmap thumbnail = gn.GenerateScreenshot("http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" + Searchedword, 1024, 768);
  FileStream imageStream = new FileStream(path1, FileMode.Create);
  thumbnail.Save(imageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
  imageStream.Close();
  downloadbutton.Visible=true;
}
```

now my problem is i have a download button to be displayed when the thumbnail has been created.. but for some reason the donwload button is not getting generated or is not visible!

I tried placing in the getscreenshot_click but it gets created even before the the thread has started running and before the thumbnail has been created.

Can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: I attempted to format the code, but the `downloadbutton.visible=true;` line doesn't fit anywhere in your example — it's out of scope.  Please try to correct the sample code.

Comment: done thanks!! i tried to make my question more generalized so had this problem!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this problem was to use webBrowseThread.join() to wait till the process is done and then say downloadbutton.visible= true !

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you don't want to do this for a webpage.  The webpage is designed so that when the click handler finishes it moves on with the page lifecycle, and after ASP takes care of a bunch of it's own stuff it will send the response to the client.  That response is being sent (or at least finalized so it can't be edited) before your background thread is finishing.

In a web environment if you're spinning off another thread you need to assume that you won't be able to edit anything for that same request in the other thread.  If you do it soon enough, or if you have a really slow server, then it *might* work, but usually it won't, and you can't ever assume that it will.

My guess is you simply don't want to create another thread, and you want the user to wait until the image is saved before returning control back to the user.

If it's really important for you to receive the request, do some stuff, send a response to the user, and then update the page *again* after something happens in your background thread it is possible, but it's a LOT of work.  (And also really sucks the resources out of your server.)  [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETBackgroundWorker-dda8d7b6/view/SourceCode) is an example on MSDN that does it, but my guess is that in this case it's overkill and you're better off not bothering.

Edit: Based on your comments the code needs to be in another thread as it's currently not in an STA thread.  Therefore the solution is to `Join` that thread in your click event handler so that you wait for it to finish before sending the response.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's true, but if you have an asynchronous handler then you still can't edit anything on the page once that handler gets spun off, or you're still blocking the user until you're done making changes (depending on how you set it up).  Using the built in ASP asynchronous stuff will result in better management of the threads, but it doesn't really address this specific problem at all.

Comment: @servy.. can u tell me how can i know that all the images have been created and the download button can be made available.. i mean where should i make the download button to be made visible..Please help me :(

Comment: @helpme Just don't do it asynchronously.  Don't make any background threads, just have all of your code in the button click handler and have the user wait until you're all done to show them anything.

Comment: @Servy, yes... I've also missed STA requirement for the thread, so asynchronous page handling is unlikely to help in this case even with thread management part. Helpme - you have to figure out yourself what you need to do - we can help with how-to/how-not-to do things, but we can't help you with what to do. Please consider drawing timelines (with pen and paper) for when stuff is available and when/where you can enable whatever you need.

Comment: @Servy, OP likely have to create separate thread for STA object... Some synchronization between threads to wait on original thread could be an option.

Comment: how will i know  the user can donwload now.. i mean how will i know the thread has ended and the user is ready to donwload!!

Comment: @helpme Did you not read my reply?  You shouldn't do anything asynchronously.  There shouldn't be any other thread, so there is no need to know when a non-existent thread finishes because it never starts.  Additionally if you have another thread the problem is not knowing when it's done, that's easy enough.  The problem is that you can't edit the response after your other thread finishes because the response is already gone; it's been sent.

Comment: @ servy .. here my problem is i should ask my user to donwload the file...can u tell me how i can download the file.. this was my question :(:(... can u show me a pusedo code or something that shows how to donwload the file...I am not creating any threads or anything.. i am asking u a solution so that i can use it... my preoblem here is .. i should give the user the capability to donwload...

Comment: @helpme You are creating a new thread in the code that you have in the OP.  Just remove all of that code and call `PerformWebBrowseOp` in the click event handler normally, rather than in a new thread.

Comment: i cant do this because generatethumnailmethod needs a ApartmentState.STA state!!otherwise it breaks!

Comment: @helpme Then add `webBrowseThread.Join()` to the end of the button click event so that it waits for your other thread to finish before continuing.